# Как объединить абзацы по отдельности с помощью регулярного выражения?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Всем привет.

Пытаюсь понять как объединить в строки все абзацы. Текст из pdf, не форматирован должным образом. Примерная логика такая:
Поиск абзаца всегда начинается с первой заглавной буквы начала строки и прекращается на точке "до" начала следующего, который также начинается с заглавной (аналогия 1-у). Затем абзацы объединяются. При этом стоить различать или учитывать когда строка внутри абзаца также может начинаться с заглавной (название города, например).

Сейчас так:

> William shakespeare is widely regarded as the
>    greatest writer the english language has ever seen,
>  whether you agree with that or not.
>   The plays are conventionally divided into the somedies,
>  
>   histories and sragedies.

А на выходе д.б:

> William shakespeare is widely regarded as the greatest writer the
>   nglish language has ever seen, whether you agree with that or not.
>   The plays are conventionally divided into the somedies, histories and
>   sragedies.

[Шаблон выражения](https://regex101.com/r/pvYcpj/1)

С Уважением.

Comment: Никак. Сначала объединяешь строки, начинающиеся с маленькой буквы, потом читаешь текст и правишь остатки руками.

Comment: Сделай в несколько шагов. Сначала `(\.)\s*\n\s*([A-Z])` замени на, скажем, `$1###$2` (ну или другой разделитель - лишь бы в тексте не встречался). Затем `\n` на пробел. И наконец разделитель на перевод строки.